# Complex integration on circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Calculate the integral of $g(z)$ along the closed path $|z-i|=2$ in the positive direction when

i)$g(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+4}$

ii)$g(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+4)^2}$

First I checked the described area

$$|z-i|=2\rightarrow |x+iy-i|=2\rightarrow|(x-0)+i(y-1)|=2$$
Which is a circle with center $C(0,1)$ and $r=2$.But I'm having trouble calculating the integral

$\int_C \frac{1}{z^2+4}dz=\int_C \frac{1}{(z-2)^2+4z}dz$

And I tried to apply the formula derived in the analytical function, but is not going well

Comment: Do you know what a residue is?

Comment: @quid I did not learn about it

Comment: Then you need to write the circle as $z=2\cos(t)+i(1+2\sin(t))$ and integrate the function in $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi$

Comment: @robjohn Can you give me a brief explanation of residue, maybe I even have learned but is not this what we call it here.

Comment: @askazy: I have added a bit to my answer about contour integration and residues (the coefficient of $\frac1{z-a}$ in the [Laurent Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) at $z=a$).

Comment: @robjohn I learn about Cauchy's integral formula, but the Laurent series is the next chapter on Complex Variables and Applications (Brown and Churchill), and this has not yet been passed.

Comment: @robjohn What I can do in ii)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle $|z-i|=2$ can be parametrized by
$$
z=2\cos(t)+i(1+2\sin(t))
$$
The first integral is then
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\overbrace{(-2\sin(t)+i2\cos(t))\,\mathrm{d}t}^{\large\mathrm{d}z}}{\underbrace{(4\cos^2(t)+3-4\sin(t)-4\sin^2(t))+i(4\cos(t)+8\sin(t)\cos(t))}_{\large z^2+4}}
$$
This is pretty complicated, but I'd start by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator to make the denominator real.

---

However, if you know contour integration, this problem becomes almost trivial by decomposing the integrand using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition):
$$
\frac1{z^2+4}=\frac1{4i}\left(\color{#C00000}{\frac1{z-2i}}-\frac1{z+2i}\right)
$$
giving an integral of $\frac\pi2$. This is because the only singularity of the integrand inside the contour of integration is $z=2i$, and the residue of $\frac1{z-2i}$ is $1$. Thus, the integral is $\frac{2\pi i}{4i}=\frac\pi2$.

---

To handle the second integral we can decompose
$$
\frac1{(z^2+4)^2}
=\frac1{32i}\left(-\frac{2i}{(z-2i)^2}\color{#C00000}{+\frac1{z-2i}}-\frac{2i}{(z+2i)^2}-\frac1{z+2i}\right)
$$
The residue of the only singularity inside the contour is $\frac1{32i}$. Thus, the integral is $\frac{2\pi i}{32i}=\frac\pi{16}$.

Comment: I think it's the latter, because the chapter talks about the contour integral, the difficult these issues is not always the function of decomposition is visually immediate.

Comment: I've added a bit more since it seems that contour integration is back on the table :-)

Comment: $(z^2+4)=(z-2i)(z+2i)$ then just apply Cauchy Integral Formula